# android studio emulator displays corrupted screen

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator

I am facing this issue, the emulator was working properly but I tried to run it today and here what I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Check if there is an update, and then choose 'Cold Boot Now' option in the menu.

[image]

after that the screen came back normal

Comment: Congratulations for finding a solution by yourself! To make your answer more useful, edit it so it is more concise and to-the-point. For example, you can put the one-line solution on the top.